# How to store 10 random numbers in an array then echo that array?

Tags: shell-script, array

Here is the part that generates the 10 random numbers.

```
MAXCOUNT=10
count=1

while [ "$count" -le $MAXCOUNT ]; do
 number=$RANDOM
 let "count += 1"
done
```

Now how do I output this to an array and then echo that array?

Comment: Why don't you print them immediately?

Comment: Because this is a school exercise and I'm still trying to figure out how to do things. Otherwise echoing them right away does make sense.

Comment: Smells like homework ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using bash? In that case, try something like that:

```
MAXCOUNT=10
count=1

while [ "$count" -le $MAXCOUNT ]; do
 number[$count]=$RANDOM
 let "count += 1"
done

echo "${number[*]}"
```

You can also replace the last line with:

```
echo "${number[@]}"
```

Some documentation here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do thanks!

Comment: Why not `number[]=$RANDOM` instead of `number[$count]=$RANDOM`?